# SQL How can I indicate if an ID ever returns a value?

Tags: python, sql

I have a table that looks like this

```
+------+------+-----------+
|Order |Prduct|Perishable?|
+------+------+-----------+
|1     |A     |Yes        |
|1     |B     |No         |
|2     |C     |No         |
|2     |D     |No         |
|2     |E     |No         |
+------+------+-----------+
```

I want to write a SQL query that returns results like

```
------+----------------------------
Order |Contains perishable products
------+----------------------------
1     |Yes                         
2     |No                          
------+----------------------------
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What you have tried so far? Please put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in the question itself.

Comment: @adam . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

If the data looks like shown strictly then you do not need to analyze a value, simply

```
SELECT `Order`, MAX(`Perishable?`) AS `Contains perishable products?`
FROM source_table_name
GROUP BY `Order`
```

For PostgreSQL - replace backticks symbols with dquotes.

---

If `Perishable?` column values may differ from shown ones then

```
SELECT `Order`, CASE WHEN SUM(`Perishable?` = 'Yes') > 0
                     THEN 'Yes'
                     ELSE 'No'
                     END AS `Contains perishable products?`
FROM source_table_name
GROUP BY `Order`
```

For MySQL `> 0` may be removed.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=124b900dd88f40a9409a7daeb5c7c696)

Comment: This many not work, if you change values to A & B. MAX function picked up the value alphabetically, as `Y` having higher ASCII value, it picked up. Please share your thoughts !

Comment: @SKM As I have said "If the data looks like shown **strictly** then ..." - i.e. I defines the conditions when the solution is applicable. What's the reason to tell what will happen if this condition is not true? More general solution added.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your point. I thought of sharing my view, that, if the value changes, then we need to rely on MAX or MIN functions

Comment: I think `MAX()` is fine and the simplest solution to this problem.  It also works in Postgres -- and in any database.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT Orders, Perishable
FROM(SELECT Orders, Perishable, count(1) cnt FROM tbl GROUP BY Orders, Perishable) qry
WHERE NOT(Perishable = 'No' AND cnt=1)
```

> This is not sorting alphabetically, but it ignores, the value you don't want !

Answer (score 0):

The next query works for MySQL & PostgreSQL as well:

```
SELECT
    OrderId, 
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN Perishable = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) > 0 
         THEN 'Yes'
         ELSE 'No'
    END Contains_perishable_products
FROM orders
GROUP BY OrderId;
```

You can try it here: [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=683598ee37a4edf55dea2f56a6a8737e&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)